# Optional arguments for newtcblisting?

Tags: tcolorbox

Is it possible to have optional arguments for `newtcblisting`?

Do I use `\ifthenelse`?

Comment: Can you make a MWE to give us something to start with?

Comment: take a look at, for example, `\DeclareTCBlisting`, Section 22.4 of the documentation

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Edit:** added the solution suggested by @cmhughes in his comment using the xparse library.

Here is an example of the tcolorbox manual section 4.13 p 302, the argument in square brackets [ ] is optional :

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}

\newtcblisting{mybox}[2][]{%
colback=red!5!white,
colframe=red!75!black,
fonttitle=\bfseries,
title=#2,#1}


\begin{document}
\begin{mybox}%[listing only]
{Listing Box}
This is my \LaTeX\ box.
\end{mybox}
\bigskip

\begin{mybox}[listing only]
{Listing Box}
This is my \LaTeX\ box.
\end{mybox}
\bigskip

\begin{mybox}[listing side text]
{Listing Box}
This is my
\LaTeX\ box.
\end{mybox}

\end{document}
```

Output:

[image]

**Second solution with the xparse library**

The format is `\DeclareTCBListing[init options]{name}{specification}{options}`
where {specifications} are those of the xparse package.

In the example, from page 441 of manual 4.13 the specifications are { s O{} m } where :

- "s" is an optional star, which will result in a value \BooleanTrue if a star is present and \BooleanFalse otherwise (as described later).
- O{} is  as for "o", but returns hdefaulti if no value is given. Should be given as O{hdefaulti}.
- m is a standard mandatory argument, which can either be a single token alone or multiple tokens surrounded by curly braces. Regardless of the input, the argument will be passed to the internal code surrounded by a brace pair. This is the xparse type specifier for a normal T E X argument

See the xparse package documentation for more information: [xparse](https://ctan.org/pkg/xparse)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}

\DeclareTCBListing{mybox}{ s O{} m }{%
colback=red!5!white,
colframe=red!75!black,
fonttitle=\bfseries,
IfBooleanTF={#1}
{listing side text}
{text side listing},
title=#3,#2}

\begin{document}

\begin{mybox}{Listing Box}
This is my
\LaTeX\ box.
\end{mybox}
\bigskip
\begin{mybox}*{Listing Box}
This is my
\LaTeX\ box.
\end{mybox}
\bigskip
\begin{mybox}[colback=yellow]
{Listing Box}
This is my
\LaTeX\ box.
\end{mybox}

\end{document}
```

[image: xparse-listing]

Comment: +1 just for reference, you can also use, for example, `\DeclareTCBListing{mybox}{O{}m}{%
colback=red!5!white,
colframe=red!75!black,
fonttitle=\bfseries,
title=#2,#1}`